# YADCF range send request on both fields filled in

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Recently we started using datatables and YADCF to show and filter through records. I was wondering if someone managed to make sure the filters with type

> range_number

and

> range_date

only send a request once both fields are filled? All I could find is the option to add a delay but that's not a great solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is no possible and I find it more user friendly to allow to filter from certain value / date without forcing user to put a value in the  "TO" value / date

p.s

I'm the yadcf author